# Play Framework: Using JPA entityManager in Interceptor Action class

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using @With(Action.class) annotation to intercept the calls to specific controller/actions. I am trying to retrieve the session from database on in the interceptor function; however the JPA helper class is not available in the Action.class interceptor method "call".

Can someone please guide on how to retrieve database entities in the interceptor functions?

Thanks.

Interceptor class:

```
public class SecuredAction extends Simple {

    public SecuredAction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Promise<Result> call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        // check isContactVerified/isEmailVerified
        String sid = getSidFromCookie(ctx);
        if (sid != null) {
            Session appSession = (Session) JPA.em().createNamedQuery("Session.findBySessionId").getSingleResult();
            User user = appSession.getUserId();
            if (user != null) {
                ctx.args.put("user", user);
                return delegate.call(ctx);
            }
        }
        Result unauthorized = Results.unauthorized("Invalid Session");
        return F.Promise.pure(unauthorized);
    }

    private String getSidFromCookie(Http.Context ctx) {
        return ctx.session().get(AppConstants.COOKIE_USER_SESSIONID);
    }
}
```

Error:
[RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap body of you action with `JPA.withTransaction`:

```
return JPA.withTransaction(
                "default",
                false, () -> {
                    String sid = getSidFromCookie(ctx);
                    if (sid != null) {
                        Session appSession = (Session) JPA.em().createNamedQuery("Session.findBySessionId").getSingleResult();
                        User user = appSession.getUserId();
                        if (user != null) {
                            ctx.args.put("user", user);
                            return delegate.call(ctx);
                        }
                    }
                    Result unauthorized = Results.unauthorized("Invalid Session");
                    return F.Promise.pure(unauthorized);
                }
        );
```

And do not annotate method with `@Transactional` if you annotated it with `@With(SecuredAction.class)`.

Comment: I ended up creating a separate database service for getting entityManager instance from Java persistence separately and calling that static method from within interceptor code. Can you suggest which of the ways(withTransaction or separate EM getInstance) should be the best practice for the mentioned case?

Comment: It is completely up to you. If your code will not give you troubles, go for it.